# Drawing to and creation of memory buffer (Windows GDI)

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, gdi

I am trying to display a users monitors inside a window which is all scaled down to the largest possible size. Currently it does not use a buffer and I am unsure how to create one for what I need.

As it dynamically draws the monitors, to stop having to redraw the entire window white, with WM_ERASEBKGND, when it is resized I think, after a lot of reading, that drawing a scale representation of the entire 'Virtual Desktop' as a memory DIB would be the best method: Therefore I can fill in the white space in between the monitors and thus make it not have to redraw them.

Bit of a multiple-part question. Is creating a memory scale virtual desktop as proposed that can be BitBlt to the display? To do this would I be using CreateDIBSection?

Currently my WM_PAINT looks like this:

```
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    innerBorder = 2;
    additional = 350;
    ratio = (static_cast<double>(sA.getDesktop()->right - sA.getDesktop()->left) / (sA.getDesktop()->bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top));

    cxMax = max((innerBorder * 2), min((cA.right - border), (((cA.bottom - border - additional) * ratio))));
    cyMax = max((innerBorder * 2) , min((cA.bottom - border - additional), (((cA.right - border) / ratio))));

    cxBorder = (cA.right - cxMax) / 2;

    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));

    //Draw Borders around virtual desktop
    Rectangle(hdc, cA.left, cA.top, cxBorder, cA.bottom);
    Rectangle(hdc, cA.right - cxBorder, cA.top, cA.right, cA.bottom);

    //Draw Borders around virtual desktop
    Rectangle(hdc, cxBorder, cA.top, cA.right - cxBorder, (border / 2));
    Rectangle(hdc, cxBorder, cyMax + (border / 2), cA.right - cxBorder, cA.bottom);

    for (i = 0; i < sA.getNumberOfMonitors(); i++)
    {
        rT = {
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.left - sA.getDesktop()->left) / (sA.getDesktop()->right - sA.getDesktop()->left)) * cxMax) + cxBorder + innerBorder,
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.top - sA.getDesktop()->top) / (sA.getDesktop()->bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top)) * cyMax) + (border / 2) + innerBorder,
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.right - sA.getDesktop()->left) / (sA.getDesktop()->right - sA.getDesktop()->left)) * cxMax) + cxBorder - innerBorder,
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top) / (sA.getDesktop()->bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top)) * cyMax) + (border / 2) - innerBorder,
        };

        SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));

        //Draw Borders around Monitor RECT
        Rectangle(hdc, rT.left - innerBorder, rT.top, rT.left, rT.bottom);
        Rectangle(hdc, rT.right, rT.top, rT.right + innerBorder, rT.bottom);
        Rectangle(hdc, rT.left - innerBorder, rT.bottom, rT.right + innerBorder, rT.bottom + innerBorder);
        Rectangle(hdc, rT.left - innerBorder, rT.top - innerBorder, rT.right + innerBorder, rT.top);


        //Draw Monitor RECT
        SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));

        Rectangle(hdc, rT.left, rT.top, rT.right, rT.bottom);

        DrawText(hdc, sA.getMonitor(i)->szDevice, strlen(sA.getMonitor(i)->szDevice), &rT, DT_CENTER | DT_BOTTOM | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);
    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Most of it is just calculating the relative sizes of the monitors to the window and is very little drawing yet. I do want it to load the fill and the borders from images. I think I have pretty much hit a brick wall. I am not sure how to continue to create the memory buffer.

EDIT: One of my many attempts at creating a memory buffer, which results in a monochromatic bitmap.

```
    hdcDisplay = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    hdcBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDisplay);

    innerBorder = 2;
    additional = 350;
    ratio = (static_cast<double>(sA.getDesktop()->right - sA.getDesktop()->left) / (sA.getDesktop()->bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top));

    cxMax = max((innerBorder * 2), min((cA.right - border), (((cA.bottom - border - additional) * ratio))));
    cyMax = max((innerBorder * 2) , min((cA.bottom - border - additional), (((cA.right - border) / ratio))));

    cxBorder = (cA.right - cxMax) / 2;

    hBitmapDraw = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDisplay, cxMax, cyMax);
    hBitmapPrevious = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmapDraw));
    GetObject(hBitmapDraw, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpDraw);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfo;

    bmpInfo.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfo.biWidth = cxMax;
    bmpInfo.biHeight = cyMax;
    bmpInfo.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfo.biBitCount = 32;
    bmpInfo.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmpInfo.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfo.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfo.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfo.biClrImportant = 0;

    //pBitmapBits = (BYTE*)malloc(sizeof(BYTE)* cxMax * 3 * cyMax);
    //hBitmapDraw = CreateDIBSection(hdcDisplay, (BITMAPINFO *)&bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, NULL, NULL, 0);
    SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmapDraw);

    SelectObject(hdcBuffer, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SelectObject(hdcBuffer, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

    SetDCPenColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(255, 255, 255));

    for (i = 0; i < sA.getNumberOfMonitors(); i++)
    {
        rT = {
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.left - sA.getDesktop()->left) / (sA.getDesktop()->right - sA.getDesktop()->left)) * cxMax) + cxBorder + innerBorder,
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.top - sA.getDesktop()->top) / (sA.getDesktop()->bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top)) * cyMax) + (border / 2) + innerBorder,
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.right - sA.getDesktop()->left) / (sA.getDesktop()->right - sA.getDesktop()->left)) * cxMax) + cxBorder - innerBorder,
            ((static_cast<float>(sA.getMonitor(i)->rcMonitor.bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top) / (sA.getDesktop()->bottom - sA.getDesktop()->top)) * cyMax) + (border / 2) - innerBorder,
        };

        SetDCPenColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(255, 255, 255));

        //Draw Borders
        Rectangle(hdcBuffer, rT.left - innerBorder, rT.top, rT.left, rT.bottom);
        Rectangle(hdcBuffer, rT.right, rT.top, rT.right + innerBorder, rT.bottom);
        Rectangle(hdcBuffer, rT.left - innerBorder, rT.bottom, rT.right + innerBorder, rT.bottom + innerBorder);
        Rectangle(hdcBuffer, rT.left - innerBorder, rT.top - innerBorder, rT.right + innerBorder, rT.top);


        SetDCPenColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(0, 0, 0));

        Rectangle(hdcBuffer, rT.left, rT.top, rT.right, rT.bottom);

        DrawText(hdcBuffer, sA.getMonitor(i)->szDevice, strlen(sA.getMonitor(i)->szDevice), &rT, DT_CENTER | DT_BOTTOM | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);
    }

    BitBlt(hdcDisplay, cxBorder, (border / 2), cxMax - cxBorder, cyMax, hdcBuffer, cxBorder, border/2, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmapPrevious);
    DeleteDC(hdcBuffer);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw into a bitmap by doing:

```
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, nWidth, nHeight);
SelectObject(memDC, memBM);
```

Just replace the `hdc` calls in your code with `memDC`. You can then call [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `memDC` as the source DC.

When you are finished with the memory DC, use `DeleteDC` to clean it up.

MSDN has an example of [Scaling an image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using this technique. You could replace the `DrawBitmap` code with your drawing logic.

Comment: CreateCompatibleBitmap creates a monochrome bitmap by default, I believe to change this I need to use CreateDIBSection with BITMAPINFO structure, that is why I am confused.

Comment: @JackHammered From the CreateCompatibleBitmap docs: "The color format of the bitmap created by the CreateCompatibleBitmap function matches the color format of the device identified by the hdc parameter." It creates a 1x1 monochrome bitmap if `nWidth == 0` and `nHeight == 0`. You only need CreateDIBSection if manipulating the bitmap's contents directly (e.g. loading/saving a bitmap file).

Comment: Apologies, it seems that it is the same format that I was just drawing in black & white and got confused.